# Measuring Distance from Point to Point Along a Path in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, distance, linear-referencing

I am looking at a village and want to find the distance from each house (point) to the pagoda (point). However, I want the distance to be measured along a path (which I digitized as a polyline) and not just the closest way (ie a route that follows the road, not just the closest path to the pagoda which includes "cutting through" other property).

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

See image below:
I need to find distance to the circled red area. 
I want the path to follow the blue, not the green.

[image]

I think this would be possible if I did a network analysis (set up a polygon restriction), but this is a rural village and I doubt there is a network dataset available.

Is it difficult to create one?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you already have a network (or prototype - the red lines).  If not, you could digitize one if the village is not too large.  You could then use [linear referencing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_linear_referencing/003900000001000000/) to locate your points on the route and then derive the appropriate M values for your points.  The ESRI documentation is essential reading, especially wrt routes (so you can set the pagoda as the end point).